# Decryption of RSA

Tags: number-theory, cryptography

I am given the following information about an RSA-encryption: $e=31671865305320609$ (public key) and $n=10e+3$. Then I am given the ciphertext $c$ which I omit here due to his length. The task is to decrypt $c$. But how to compute the secret key $d$? A factorisation of $n$ seems to be inappropriate to me. Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Why does that seem inappropriate? What you need is an inverse $d$ to $e$ modulo $\varphi(n)$. To find an inverse modulo $\varphi(n)$, you need to know what $\varphi(n)$ is. To find $\varphi(n)$, you need to know the prime factorization of $n$.

Comment: $d=152575027899837665$ I don't see a way you obtain it without factorization of n

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor(10*31671865305320609%2B3)